# Is there a proutil option to list all the tables within all the schemas of an OpenEdge database

Tags: database, schema, openedge

I am trying to list the tables in each schema of an OpenEdge database.

I normally use dbutil  -C tabanalys but on the system I am currently working on it is taking far too long to run (currently over 4 hours).

Does anyone know of a tool I can use in proEnv to get a list of the schemas and the tables within those schemas.

Dev tools not an option on this site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a kind-of-way to do this but suspect it may not work in all scenarios...

I used the VIEWB2 option on proutil to list all the schemas (areas) and their objects.  Note: this is in respect to Alternate Buffer Pool Processing and I'm not too sure what implications that may have but it worked for me.

proutil  -C viewB2

Answer (score 1):

Not via proutil.

You would typically write a 4GL query to extract that info.

```
for each _file no-lock where _tbl-type = "t":
  display _file-name.
end.
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks Tom.  Unfortunately I can't use the dev tools on this site; they have no dev license.  I found a workaround but suspect it may not be suitable in all situations - I'd be interested in your input on my answer.

Comment: Do they have SQL-92 enabled?  You could always whip together a sql equivalent of the above and run it with sqlexp.

Comment: Ah, of course - I'll remember this for next time!  Cheers